# Keras: Concate result of a model to other features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a model using Keras which takes texts and other features as inputs.

I'm planning to do the below:

1. Train a LSTM model with texts, output a 32 dimension result.
2. Concat output of LSTM model (32 dimensions) with other features (15 dimensions) and generate a 47 dimension input.
3. Train another model with this 47 dimension input.

How do I do this Concat operation in Keras? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add some code? What you've tried? Sample input? S/O isn't a code writing or consulting service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
tf.keras.layers.concatenate(
    inputs, axis=-1, **kwargs
)
```

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate) is an example provided by official docs

Some key things to look for though:

- Choose the right loss function which might be the weighted sum of some separate losses
- whether it worth training the networks jointly or separately